# Definition of dual in boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Im taking a course in discrete mathematics and my professors definition of what the dual of a boolean expression does not match all the resources I've seen elsewhere and is confusing me. Here is an example of what he says a dual is:

[dual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hCzy.png)

My understanding is the dual is found by changing all the 'or' values to 'and' and vice-versus. The complement is changing the sign of the value.

So woudn't the dual of (x or y or z) be

(x and y and z)

and the complement be

'
(~x and ~y and ~z)

And his definition of "dual" which is

~x and ~y and ~z

be the complement of the expression and also the dual?

ORIGIONAL (x or y or z)
DUAL(according to professor) (~x and ~y and ~z)

Comment: Is it just me, or does that link lead to a "privacy error"? May you type out your professor's example of a dual?

Comment: @Accelerator     Here is the example and his definition of dual:                                           
                            ORIGIONAL (x or y or z)                                            
                                                                DUAL (~x and ~y and ~z)

Comment: A google search will show you that your question has been asked and answered several times before on MSE.